# Curve homotopic to $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm triying to understand why the parametrization in the example 2.12 of Conway's book (page 119) is homotopic to $0$.

We want to prove that $\displaystyle \int \limits _0^\infty \frac{x^{-c}}{1+x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi c}$, $0<c<1$>

The parametrization indeed:

Use the "keyhole" contour.
Let $r\to 0,~R\to \infty ,~\delta\to 0$. Let $L_1$ be the line segment $[r+\delta i,R+\delta i];$ $\gamma _R$ the part of the circle $|z|=R$ from $R+\delta i$ counterclockwise to $R-\delta i$; $L_2$ the line segment $[R-\delta i,r-\delta i]$; and $\gamma _r$ the part of the circle $|z|=r$ from $r-\delta i$ clockwise to $r+\delta i$. Put $\gamma =L_1+\gamma _R+L_2+\gamma _r$.

The example says that $\gamma \sim 0$. Why?

Comment: Just fill in the keyhole. Conway should specify in what domain he’s making the statement, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the keyhole contour, note that $z=0$ is a branch point, and the branch cut is chosen as the positive real axis. The sum of four integrals along the entire contour $\gamma$, which includes four parts "$L_1,\gamma_R, L_2, \gamma_r$" should equal the residue at $z_0=e^{i\pi}=-1$, which is a simple pole.

$$I_{L_1}+I_{\gamma_R}+I_{L_2}+I_{\gamma_r}=2\pi i\cdot \text{Res}(z=z_0)$$